# $.get JSON request + fill and returning ARRAY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started to work with a mobile framework LungoJS. Me and javascript not work quite fine but really i want modify this original code:

**ORIGINAL.JS**

```
var mock = function() {
        var mock = [];
        for (var i=1; i<=5; i++){
            mock.push({
                id: i,
                name: 'name n'+i,
                description: 'description n'+i
            })
        }
        lng.View.Template.List.create({
            container_id: 'lives',
            template_id: 'show_music_template',
            data: mock    
        })
    }
    return {
        mock: mock
    }



})(LUNGO, App);
```

This original code works fine and it's easy, now I want do request using $.get who returns a JSON file and fill array like the ORIGINAL.JS:

**JSON RESULT:**

```
    {"result":[
    {"id":"52","username":"jgali","image":"Prova_(live)387.jpeg","name":"Prova (live)","type":"music","language":"Catalan","category":"8","tags":"indie, dine prova, indie live","description":"Aquesta es una prova online de reidiou","licence":"Reidiou License","played":"54","record_time":"45","facebook_id":"1052266203_2342869925158","twitter_hash":"#Provalive","create_date":"2011-11-01 13:04:21"},
    {"id":"52","username":"jgali","image":"Prova_(live)387.jpeg","name":"Prova (live)","type":"music","language":"Catalan","category":"8","tags":"indie, dine prova, indie live","description":"Aquesta es una prova online de reidiou","licence":"Reidiou License","played":"54","record_time":"45","facebook_id":"1052266203_2342869925158","twitter_hash":"#Provalive","create_date":"2011-11-01 13:04:21"}
]}
```

**SERVICE.JS**

```
var mock = function() {
        var mock = [];
        var url = 'http://localhost/app/rest/podcasts';
        var data = {};

        //lng.Service.get = $get
        lng.Service.get(url, data,function(response) { 
            var array = [];
            //Do something with response
             jQuery.each(response.result, function() {
                    mock.push({
                        id: this.id,
                        name: this.name,
                        description: this.description
                    })    
            });
            document.write(mock[1].id);
        });
        lng.View.Template.List.create({
            container_id: 'lives',
            template_id: 'show_music_template',
            data: mock  
        })  
    }
    return {
        mock: mock
    }
```

The problem is outside loop i can't use "mock" array. Sure I make a several mistake...but anybody knows what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: remove the `var` like `mock=[];` to declare a global array and you will be fine

Comment: Using globals is an anti-pattern and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$.get()` needs time to execute, and is therefore asynchronous. Asynchronous calls like this involve the use of a `callback` function. To get access to the `mock` array you need to nest anything within this callback.

You can also force AJAX calls to be synchronous in jQuery (though I, and the docs, warn against this); according to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active.

Comment: "To get access to the mock array you need to nest anything within this callback." How I get it? 

Thanks for your answer

Comment: @galix85 Do you know what nesting and a callback function is? If not, I recommend some basic reading in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! I solved the problem using callback as you said.

I post the code if anybody are interested:

```
App.Services = (function(lng, app, undefined) {

var mock = function() {
        var mock = new Array();
        var url = 'http://localhost/app/rest/podcasts';
        var data = {};

        function getData (url,data,mock,callbackFnk){
            lng.Service.get(url, data,function(response) {
                //Do something with response
                // now we are calling our own callback function
                if(typeof callbackFnk == 'function'){
                  callbackFnk.call(this, response);
                }else{
                    document.write("Error");   
                }

            });
        }
        getData(url,data,mock,function(response){

            jQuery.each(response.result, function() {
                    mock.push({
                        id: this.id,
                        name: this.name,
                        description: this.description
                    })

            });

            lng.View.Template.List.create({
            container_id: 'lives',
            template_id: 'show_music_template',
            data: mock
            })
        })     
    }

    return {
        mock: mock
    }

})(LUNGO, App);
```